# Direct product of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, direct-product

> Can a direct product of two free groups of rank $2$ be a non trivial amalgamated free product over $\Bbb Z$?

I read that it can't be done.

I tried to see what the edge stabilizers of the amalgamated tree might look like if such analysis was possible using the fact that if two hyperbolic elements commute (such as belonging to a different factor in the direct product), then their invariant axis would be the same but haven't made any progress.

Can you give me any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Does "amalgamated product" means "amalgamated free product"? Or on the other hand does it mean "amalgamated free product or HNN amalgamation"?

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean amalgamated free product, with embeddings of $\Bbb Z$

Comment: No, this would not be possible. But the proof that I know is a bit long and requires some concepts from coarse topology such as coarse separation. Maybe there is a purely algebraic proof based on two facts: The vertex groups of the supposed amalgam will have to be finitely presented and the direct product of two free groups contains very few finitely presented subgroups.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Can you point me somewhere to read about that last sentence about the finitely presented subgroups?

Comment: I think the phrasing "amalgamated product" is correct (and even better) to mean "amalgamated free product".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $F_1,F_2$ be non-cyclic finitely generated groups. Then $F_1\times F_2$ is not amalgamated product or HNN extension over a cyclic subgroup.

Let $F_1,F_2$ be non-cyclic finitely generated groups. Suppose that $G=F_1\times F_2$ acts unboundedly, inversion-free, on a tree $T$ with  cyclic edge stabilizers.

Suppose that each element of $F_1$ acts with a fixed vertex. Then $F_1$ has a fixed vertex (this is a general fact on tree actions of f.g. groups). Let $T_1$ be the set of vertices fixed by $F_1$. Then $T_1$ is a subtree, and is $F_2$-invariant. By minimality, we deduce that $T=T_1$, and hence $F_1$ acts trivially. Since $F_1$ is not cyclic, it follows that edge stabilizers are not cyclic, contradiction.

So some element $g_1$ of $F_1$ is loxodromic, with axis $A_1$. Similarly, some element $g_2$ of $F_2$ is loxodromic, with axis $A_2$. Since $F_2$ commutes with $g_1$, $F_2$ preserves $A_1$, and hence $A_2=A_1$, and since $F_1$ commutes with $g_2$, $F_1$ preserves $A_2=A_1$. So the action preserves an axis, hence by minimality $T$ is reduced to an axis.

Hence $G$ modulo a cyclic normal subgroup is trivial, of order $2$, infinite cyclic, or dihedral. This is excluded by the assumptions.

Comment: Can you explain why $F_1$ fixes a vertex? I know that's the case when an orbit is bounded, but what about it here?

Comment: I never said that $F_1$ fixes a vertex. I said that if every element fixes a vertex, then it fixes a vertex. This is true for every finitely generated group $G$: if $G$ acts inversion-free with no fixed vertex on a (nonempty) tree, then there is a loxodromic element. This can be found in Serre's book.